# How can I correctly view my Vue.js app after using npm run build

Tags: docker, vue.js

I have a Vue.js app, which runs correctly when I execute `npm run serve`

After running `npm run build`, I get a "dist" directory which container the minified html, css, images, etc.

However, I can't seem to view the html files in the browser correctly.

I've tried running a simple python server to serve the directory.

`python3 -m http.server 8080`

However, this causes a huge amount of 404 errors and nothing is displayed.

The app does work correctly after npm run serve.

What am I missing?

I'm doing this, so in my Dockerfile, I can have a multistage build, where I only need to push the minified files.

Answer (score -1):

You could map `npm run start` (usual naming to run a built project) to `serve`
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#previewing-locally